# Print the affected rows in SQL Server raw query sequelize

Tags: node.js

I am trying to print the affected rows from a updated raw query and I get "undefined"

I tried different ways but it doesn't work

```
method(ARGS) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            const self = this;

            co(function* () {
                connection.query(`
                    UPDATE table set column )
                    `, {
                        replacements: {
                           bind variables
                        },
                        type: UPDATE
                    }).then((results, metadata) => {
                        console.log("response", metadata);
                        resolve(metadata);
                      }).catch(function (err) {
                        console.error(err));
                        resolve({
                          err
                   });
                    });
                });
        });
    }
}
```

Print the affected rows

Answer (score 0):

Update function of sequelize returns a number of affected rows (first parameter of result array)
so to get the number of rows affected you need to print results[0]